# How do I print a counter function using EPL 2?

Tags: epl

I can create a  counter function using EPL, as well as print ascii text but I cannot figure out how to print a counter function in EPL. I have attempted to use the programming manual however the example used to print a counter does not work. I believe my error lies in the "Prompt." Here is what I have so far:

N

A50,150,0,4,1,1,N,C0

C0,1,12,C,+1,"-Enter Serial Number:"

P1

How do I print the contents of a counter using EPL?
Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"The EPL2 "C" (counter) command used for creating an incrementing or decrementing field will only work within a form." Read this [link](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/eltron/epl2/epl2_counter.htm).